# How to correctly allocate memory for the query string?

Tags: c, postgresql, malloc

I need to execute a sql query in a C program. I use libpq to connect to Postgresql.

```
char *formatted_query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT %d OFFSET %d";
char *query;
PGconn *conn;
PGresult *res;
int limit;
int offset;
/* here is connect to base get some data from user (like limit, offset etc.) */
sprintf(query, formatted_query, limit, offset);
res = PQexec(conn, query);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to allocate enough memory for `query`
Of course I can do it like this:

```
char query[999];
```

But I think that this way is wrong. And if I do:

```
char *query = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeof(formatted_query));
```

It may happen that not enough memory is allocated (for example, limit or offset will be MAX_INT).
How do I correctly allocate memory for the query string?

Comment: `char *query = malloc(snprintf(NULL,0,formatted_query, limit, offset)+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using `PQexecParams`. For integers you unfortunately still have to format them to text, but you can use a simple static buffer for that.

```
PGconn *conn;
PGresult *res;

#define MAX_INT4_DIGITS 11

const char *query = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2";
Oid paramtypes[] = {INT4OID, INT4OID};
char *paramvalues[2];
char limitstr[MAX_INT4_DIGITS];
char offsetstr[MAX_INT4_DIGITS];

snprintf(offsetstr, MAX_INT4_DIGITS, "%d", limit);
snprintf(limitstr, MAX_INT4_DIGITS, "%d", offset); 

paramvalues[0] = limitstr;
paramvalues[1] = offsetstr;

res = PQexecParams(conn, query, 2, paramtypes, paramvalues, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Using parameterised queries isn't too much of a big deal when you just have a couple of integer parameters, but it becomes vital when you're using user-supplied strings. Otherwise you get yourself in a horrible mess with quoting and escaping against SQL injection.

The libpq binary protocol interface is actually a lot more convenient, but unfortunately it doesn't work across different architectures (endianness, word size, etc).

For a more convenient interface that automates some of the low level fiddling with libpq, take a look at [libpqtypes](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/).

Comment: Er, whoops. Rather. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate how many symbols will take both numbers, but simplest way is to do:

```
// max 32 bit unsigned integer number is 4294967295 (10 symbols)
int maxPossibleStringLength = strlen(formatted_query) + 2*10 + 1; // don't forget 0 symbol at end
char *query = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * maxPossibleStringLength);
```